# Query that connects Year and Month into a single column where dates are timestamped (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-date-functions, date-manipulation

I have a table where the values in the date column are represented like this

```
2018-01-22 11:26:28.000
```

I run the following query in order to group the sums given the month/ year:

```
select 
    sum(number) as 'Number', 
    month(Datetime) as 'Month', 
    year(datetime) as 'Year' 
from 
    tablename
group by 
    month(datetime), year(datetime) 
order by 
    year(datetime), month
```

Which returns an output like this:

```
Number | Month  | Year
1000   |   01   |  2018
2000   |   02   |  2018
```

What I now need to need is to concatenate the month and year column into one without changing the table/date column itself. I am aware of this query:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([year]  AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
        CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + 
        CAST([day]   AS VARCHAR(2)) 
   AS DATE) AS DateTim FROM table
```

However, I cant get this to work given the fact that the table is not structured having month/year as a column to begin with. I also cannot change the table or create a new one.

The desired end result would be a query that returns results similar to this:

```
Number | NewDate
1000   |  01-2018
2000   |  02-2018
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is formatting the display value of a datetime value. It should be done on the client side, not directly from the database.

Comment: So you already have the year and month taken from the column. Just put those into the other query you have and you have it how you want it.

Comment: Have you tried this: 'SELECT ..., CAST( month(Datetime) as VARCHAR( 2)) + '-' + CAST( year(datetime) as VARCHAR( 4 ))' ?